# Customize Liferay search portlet

Tags: liferay, hook, liferay-6, portlet

I want to customize the search portlet as shown below. How can I achieve this using a plugin-hook?

[image: I want to customize search portlet like this]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about web-content search?

Comment: Nope sir. I am asking about the another Search portlet under Tools Category. Thankyou. Hoping for your response.

Comment: Looking at the screen reveals that you require handy UI and functional changes. Well, "Search Portlet" files are located at \portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\search. You can start traversing it and over-ride required JSPs using HOOK. But, first you need to learn to create HOOKs, you can refer https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-a-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-10-en

Comment: Thank you I will try that. Wish me luck! Thank you very much :)

Comment: inside the search folder.. what jsp should i use to hook?

Comment: You can start with search.jsp Top search field and icons are appearing from there. While left side category filters are appearing from the files of facets folder.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Why don't you create your own search portlet? That would need less effort, would be independent of the exact Liferay version  and would offer more options for implementations.

Comment: Could you provide some links on how will i achieve that. Thanks

Comment: You can learn about [tag:portlet] from Liferay development guide and the numerous tutorials available on dev.liferay.com to create portlets in liferay. And you use your own UI but in the back-end you can directly consume Liferay's Search API to get your results.